# Is it True that you can add Syntax to the Editor Form Field Type?

Tags: form-fields-types, highlighting

I was looking into the Editor Form field and I came upon this page:

https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/20062

Which shows this:

```
<field name="css" type="editor" filter="raw" editor="codemirror|none" syntax="css"/>
<field name="js" type="editor" filter="raw" editor="codemirror|none" syntax="js"/>
```

Notice the: `syntax="css"` and `syntax="js"`

I was not aware that this feature is present in Joomla and the documentation does not show that it is. So I obviously tested it in a test module but can't seem to see a difference. But I keep wondering.

Anyone knows if this is present or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but support for this feature depends on specific editor. It's used mainly by code editors like CodeMirror, not by WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE.